# Facebook Oauth not working after I packed the chrome plugin

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm using  `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` to make user can login with FB OAuth 2.0, which is working perfectly under unpacked.
However, when I packed the chrome extension.
And the Authentication totally failed.

I just want to confirm is anyone successfully integrate the Facebook OAuth with the Chrome extension. Maybe the FB whitelist policy totally won't make this work at all.

[image: inline]
[image: inline]

Answer (score 0):

Can you whitelist redirect URI's in **manifest.json**

**Ex:**

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*.facebook.com;
```

## EDIT 1:

Following code for Facebook OAuth Login is working properly:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Facebook Sample",

  "description": "Facebook Sample",

  "version": "1",

  "manifest_version": 2,

  "minimum_chrome_version": "29",

  "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
   },

  "permissions": ["identity", "https://*.facebook.com/*"]

}
```

**index.html and index.js**

```js
onload = function() {
  var login = document.getElementById("login");

  login.onclick = function() {
    var redirectUrl = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL();
    var clientId = "1ac94815c30440efa6f7de3c0d529515";
    var authUrl = "https://facebook.com/oauth/authorize/?" +
        "client_id=" + clientId + "&" +
        "response_type=token&" +
        "redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl);
 
    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({url: authUrl, interactive: true},
        function(responseUrl) {
      console.log(responseUrl);
      var accessToken = responseUrl.substring(responseUrl.indexOf("=") + 1);
      console.log(accessToken);

      
    });
  };
};

var facebookAPI = function(accessToken) {
  this.request = function(method, arguments, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      callback(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
    };

    xhr.open("GET", "https://api.facebook.com/v1/" + method + "?access_token=" + accessToken);
    xhr.send();
  };
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Facebook Login</title>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="login">Facebook Log in</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: THanks so much~ it didn't work at all. `  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*.facebook.com  https://connect.facebook.net https://graph.facebook.com ; object-src 'self'"`

Comment: I just want to confirm is anyone successfully integrate the Facebook OAuth with the Chrome extension. Maybe the FB whitelist policy totally won't make this work at all.

Comment: @newBike: Please see my edit, I tried sample code and it worked without any issues

Comment: did you pack you chrome extension? I got this problem after packing it.